# mongodb having multiple conditions for $ne

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to do a query where I exclude certain borough names such as Brooklyn, Queens, and Staten Island, I was able to exclude just one but can not figure out how to exclude more then just one

excluding just one: 
db.rest.find({ borough : {$ne : "Brookyln"}});

this worked just to exclude one and so I looked around to see how I can do multiple and tried

db.rest.find({ borough : {$ne : ["Brooklyn", "Queens", "Staten Island"]}});

which did not work, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried `db.rest.find({ borough : {$nin : ["Brooklyn", "Queens", "Staten Island"]}});` ? More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/

Comment: I didn't think about using $nin.... , That worked thank you for the help. Do you know why $ne does not work for the array?

Comment: $ne most likely requires the specified document field value to exactly match the given array, which will most likely evaluate to true for you most/all of the time

Answer (score 57):

You can use the $nin operator:

```
db.rest.find({ borough : {$nin : ["Brooklyn", "Queens", "Staten Island"]}});
```

Ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!